# Get recent or frequent playlist using Windows Media Player SDK

Tags: c#, .net, com, windows-media-player, wmp

*Neither the official documentation nor the object browser in Visual Studio showed me how to access Windows Media Player recent files playlist? Or the frequent items?*

i.e. the one's that can be witnessed in the Windows 7 jump-list
How To Display Recent Files Instead Of Frequent Files In Windows Media Player Jump List
http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-display-recent-files-instead-of-frequent-files-in-windows-media-player-jump-list/

#### WMP Docs

Playlists and the PlaylistCollection Object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564122(v=vs.85).aspx

Static and Auto Playlists
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564402(v=vs.85).aspx

Playlists and the MediaCollection Object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564121(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Not every feature is exposed in the Automation interface.

Comment: @Hans Should i read your comment as the recent / frequent playlists features specifically are not exposed as well?